# SQLAlchemy Relationships No Foreign Key

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I've reflected an existing database and overwritten some columns. 
Can someone tell me what's wrong with the following?

```
metadata = MetaData(engine)
class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'users'
    __table__ = Table('dim_user', metadata, 
                      Column('user_id', Integer, primary_key=True), 
                      autoload=True)
    projects = relationship('Project', back_populates='users')

class Project(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'projects'
    __table__ = Table('dim_project', metadata,
                      Column('project_id', Integer, primary_key=True), 
                      Column('user_id', Integer, ForeignKey('users.user_id')),
                      autoload=True)
```

When I try to query anything I get:

```
NoForeignKeysError: Could not determine join condition between parent/child tables on relationship User.projects - there are no foreign keys linking these tables.  Ensure that referencing columns are associated with a ForeignKey or ForeignKeyConstraint, or specify a 'primaryjoin' expression.
```

Comment: You explicitly pass the declarative model a table to use with [`__table__`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/extensions/declarative/table_config.html#using-a-hybrid-approach-with-table) overriding `__tablename__` and `Table` construction in general. The explicit table has name `dim_user`. You then try to reference `users.user_id` in `Project`, but the table does not exist in the metadata, because no such table has been created.

Answer (score 0):

As @ilja-everilä already tried to convey in his comment, your model is not consitent: you are explicitly defining `__table__` properties, which override then `__tablename__` properties -- you have to find out *which* of the are the right ones. In your `ForeignKey` definition you refer to the `__tablename__` of `User` but not the `__table__` definition.

In your `relationship` definition of `User.projects` you don't explicitly refer a `ForeigKey` nor a join condition, and since your meta data is messed up (see above) sqlalchemy is unable to determine automatically what you want.