# SQLAlchemy - Relationship with "indirect" Foreign Key

Tags: python, database, sqlite, database-design, sqlalchemy

## Context

I'm using SQLAlchemy (v2) to set up a database for an application, and I'm trying to model some relationships on my data.
The relationships look similar to this diagram.

[image: ER-Diagram]

So I have these hierarchical many to one relationships, where `Cluster`s belong to `SubSubtype`s, which in turn belong to a `Subtype`.
`Sample`s are similar, but they might only have a `Subtype` and not a `SubSubtype`.

## Problem

Now I have the problem, that in my `cluster` table, I only want one reference to the `subtype_id` (preferably on `subsubtype.subtype_id`), and similarly in my `Sample` table I only want to reference `subtype_id` once.

This should be no problem, when specifying an [alternate join condition](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/orm/join_conditions.html#specifying-alternate-join-conditions) or a [custom FK-relationship](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/orm/join_conditions.html#specifying-alternate-join-conditions), which I've tried.

I have some code (can be found close to the bottom), that does that, but when I run it, it successfully creates the database schema, but fails on inserting the objects.
I get a `NoForeignKeysError`, and SQLAlchemy tells me that

> there are no foreign keys linking [the subtype and cluster] tables.

and to

> Ensure that referencing columns are associated with a ForeignKey or ForeignKeyConstraint, or specify a 'primaryjoin' expression.

And while indeed, there is no direct connection, I specified a `primaryjoin` expression *and* the `foreign_keys` to use (in various combinations, with and without).

Also, when I subsequently visualize the database schema in the generated file, I get the following Diagram, which seems to suggest, that what I want should work.

[image: DataGrip Diagram]

This actually seems like a bug with SQLAlchemy to me (bad error message at the very least), but I've learned that things like these are usually user errors, so I'm coming here for second opinions first.

I've put the full error message (excluding the generated SQL) at the end, since details tags don't seem to work on SO.

I also tried to use the `hybrid_property` decorator for `subtype` (and/or `subsubtype`), which would work for `Cluster`, but afaics not for `Sample`, because I still don't see how I could get at the `SubSubtype`s without the

## Question

How can I model these relationships in SQLAlchemy without duplicating the references, and preferably using a declarative style.

Changing the schema would be okay iff it is necessary to achieve the goal.

### Similar Questions

I've had a look at these other questions, and while somewhat similar, they don't really help me here.

- [Sql - Indirect Foreign Key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20842756/sql-indirect-foreign-key)
  Different setup, not SQLAlchemy specific.
- [SQLAlchemy - How to add indirect relationships through more than one model?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76970237/sqlalchemy-how-to-add-indirect-relationships-through-more-than-one-model)
  Somewhat related, but using old imperative style from v1.4 and no answer.
- [SQLAlchemy Association Proxy - Preventing Duplicate Entries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48958612/sqlalchemy-association-proxy-preventing-duplicate-entries)
  Different problem and old-style imperative code.
- [SQLAlchemy Relationships No Foreign Key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43089073/sqlalchemy-relationships-no-foreign-key)
  Similar error message, but different setup, and also old-style imperative code.

I haven't found much more that seems relevant, but would be happy about someone pointing me to an applicable solution.

## Code

Here's a (somewhat) minimal reproducible example:

```py
from pathlib import Path
from typing import List, Optional

from sqlalchemy import ForeignKey, String, create_engine, event, Engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import Mapped, mapped_column, relationship, DeclarativeBase, Session


class Base(DeclarativeBase):
    pass


@event.listens_for(Engine, "connect")
def sqlite_pragma_enforce_foreign_keys(dbapi_connection, _):
    """
    This is necessary to enforce foreign key constraints on SQLite.
    Cf. `SQLAlchemy docs <https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/dialects/sqlite.html#foreign-key-support>`_.

    :param dbapi_connection: The database connection.
    :param _: connection_record?
    """
    cursor = dbapi_connection.cursor()
    cursor.execute("PRAGMA foreign_keys=ON")
    cursor.close()


class Sample(Base):
    __tablename__ = "sample"

    id: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(String(16), primary_key=True)
    """A unique identifier for the sample, aka. the "scount"."""

    sequence: Mapped[str] = mapped_column()
    """The actual genome data/consensus sequences. May only contain valid characters, cf. :meth:`_validate_sequence`."""

    subtype_id: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(ForeignKey("subtype.id"))
    """The ID of the sub- or sub-subtype of this sample."""

    subsubtype_id: Mapped[Optional[str]] = mapped_column(ForeignKey("subsubtype.id"))
    """The ID of the sub-subtype of this sample."""

    subtype: Mapped["Subtype"] = relationship(back_populates="samples")
    """The :class:`Subtype` of this sample."""

    subsubtype: Mapped[Optional["SubSubtype"]] = relationship(back_populates="samples")
    """The :class:`SubSubtype` of this sample."""


class Subtype(Base):
    __tablename__ = "subtype"

    id: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(String(3), primary_key=True)
    """The id of this subtype."""

    subsubtypes: Mapped[List["SubSubtype"]] = relationship()
    """A list of :class:`SubSubtype` clades under this subtype."""

    clusters: Mapped[List["Cluster"]] = relationship()
    """A list of :class:`Cluster` objects under this sub-subtype."""

    samples: Mapped[List[Sample]] = relationship()
    """All :class:`Sample` objects of this subtype."""


class SubSubtype(Base):
    __tablename__ = "subsubtype"

    subtype_id: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(ForeignKey("subtype.id"), primary_key=True)
    """Sub-subtypes belong to a :class:`Subtype`, which is their "parent", this is identified by the ``subtype_id``."""

    id: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(String(16), primary_key=True)
    """The sub-subtype specific part of the id."""

    subtype: Mapped[Subtype] = relationship(back_populates="subsubtypes")
    """Sub-subtypes have a :class:`Subtype` as parent."""

    clusters: Mapped[List["Cluster"]] = relationship()
    """A list of :class:`Cluster` objects under this sub-subtype."""

    samples: Mapped[List[Sample]] = relationship()
    """All :class:`Sample` objects of this subtype."""


class Cluster(Base):
    __tablename__ = "cluster"

    subtype_id: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(ForeignKey("subsubtype.subtype_id"), primary_key=True)
    """The ID of the sub- or sub-subtype of this cluster."""

    subsubtype_id: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(ForeignKey("subsubtype.id"), primary_key=True)
    """The ID of the sub-subtype of this cluster."""

    id: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(String(10), primary_key=True)
    """The cluster specific part of the name/id, e.g., in case of "A1_1", it would be "1"."""

    subtype: Mapped["Subtype"] = relationship(
        primaryjoin=subtype_id == Subtype.id,
        foreign_keys=[subtype_id],
        back_populates="clusters",
    )
    """The :class:`Subtype` of this cluster."""

    subsubtype: Mapped["SubSubtype"] = relationship(back_populates="clusters")
    """The :class:`SubSubtype` of this cluster."""


if __name__ == '__main__':
    engine = create_engine("sqlite:///:memory:", echo=True)
    Base.metadata.create_all(engine)

    subtype = Subtype(id="A")
    subsubtype = SubSubtype(subtype_id="A", id="1")
    cluster = Cluster(subtype_id="A", subsubtype_id="1", id="1")

    with Session(engine) as session:
        session.add_all([subtype, subsubtype, cluster])
        session.commit()
```

## Exception

Full output

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/fynn/Desktop/HIV/HIV-Clustering/venv/lib64/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/relationships.py", line 2418, in _determine_joins
    self.primaryjoin = join_condition(
                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/fynn/Desktop/HIV/HIV-Clustering/venv/lib64/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/util.py", line 123, in join_condition
    return Join._join_condition(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/fynn/Desktop/HIV/HIV-Clustering/venv/lib64/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/selectable.py", line 1358, in _join_condition
    raise exc.NoForeignKeysError(
sqlalchemy.exc.NoForeignKeysError: Can't find any foreign key relationships between 'subtype' and 'cluster'.

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/fynn/.config/JetBrains/PyCharm2023.2/scratches/scratch_6.py", line 138, in <module>
    subtype = Subtype(id="A")
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "<string>", line 4, in __init__
  File "/home/fynn/Desktop/HIV/HIV-Clustering/venv/lib64/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/state.py", line 561, in _initialize_instance
    manager.dispatch.init(self, args, kwargs)
  File "/home/fynn/Desktop/HIV/HIV-Clustering/venv/lib64/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/event/attr.py", line 487, in __call__
    fn(*args, **kw)
  File "/home/fynn/Desktop/HIV/HIV-Clustering/venv/lib64/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/mapper.py", line 4391, in _event_on_init
    instrumenting_mapper._check_configure()
  File "/home/fynn/Desktop/HIV/HIV-Clustering/venv/lib64/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/mapper.py", line 2386, in _check_configure
    _configure_registries({self.registry}, cascade=True)
  File "/home/fynn/Desktop/HIV/HIV-Clustering/venv/lib64/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/mapper.py", line 4199, in _configure_registries
    _do_configure_registries(registries, cascade)
  File "/home/fynn/Desktop/HIV/HIV-Clustering/venv/lib64/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/mapper.py", line 4240, in _do_configure_registries
    mapper._post_configure_properties()
  File "/home/fynn/Desktop/HIV/HIV-Clustering/venv/lib64/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/mapper.py", line 2403, in _post_configure_properties
    prop.init()
  File "/home/fynn/Desktop/HIV/HIV-Clustering/venv/lib64/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/interfaces.py", line 579, in init
    self.do_init()
  File "/home/fynn/Desktop/HIV/HIV-Clustering/venv/lib64/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/relationships.py", line 1636, in do_init
    self._setup_join_conditions()
  File "/home/fynn/Desktop/HIV/HIV-Clustering/venv/lib64/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/relationships.py", line 1881, in _setup_join_conditions
    self._join_condition = jc = JoinCondition(
                                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/fynn/Desktop/HIV/HIV-Clustering/venv/lib64/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/relationships.py", line 2305, in __init__
    self._determine_joins()
  File "/home/fynn/Desktop/HIV/HIV-Clustering/venv/lib64/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/relationships.py", line 2439, in _determine_joins
    raise sa_exc.NoForeignKeysError(
sqlalchemy.exc.NoForeignKeysError: Could not determine join condition between parent/child tables on relationship Subtype.clusters - there are no foreign keys linking these tables.  Ensure that referencing columns are associated with a ForeignKey or ForeignKeyConstraint, or specify a 'primaryjoin' expression.
```

Comment: `cluster` shouldn't have a FK to `subtype`, since the subtype is implied by `subsubtype_id`. When you need the subtype details, you use another join.

Comment: @Barmar there is no explicit FK to `subtype`, it's specified as `ForeignKey("subsubtype.subtype_id")`, and `subsubtype_id` doesn't imply subtype, because it's only one part of the composite primary key of `SubSubtype`, so it alone is not enough to reference that. Thanks for taking a look anyways!

Comment: In that case you don't want two separate ForeignKey declarations from Cluster to SubSubType, you want to create a composite ForeignKeyConstraint as illustrated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7506168/2144390).

Comment: @GordThompson I think you're right. I kept going back to the basics and re-reading the docs, and it seems, that defining [composite FKs is not possible with declarative style](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/core/constraints.html#defining-foreign-keys). Thanks for the comment.

Comment: It is indeed possible, we just need to use `ForeignKeyConstraint()` like [this](https://gist.github.com/gordthompson/8d540f8b84c4460b1e3097e2898f4674).

Comment: @GordThompson THANK YOU! This looks exactly right. If you turn this into an answer (two sentences is enough), I will gladly accept!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `SubSubType` has a composite Primary Key, `Cluster` needs a composite Foreign Key. Instead of using `ForeignKey()` separately on each column, use `ForeignKeyConstraint()` in `__table_args__`, like this:

```py
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, ForeignKey, ForeignKeyConstraint, String
from sqlalchemy.orm import DeclarativeBase, Mapped, mapped_column

engine = create_engine("sqlite://")


class Base(DeclarativeBase):
    pass


class SubType(Base):
    __tablename__ = "subtype"

    id: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(primary_key=True)


class SubSubType(Base):
    __tablename__ = "subsubtype"

    subtype_id: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(
        ForeignKey("subtype.id"), primary_key=True
    )
    id: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(String(16), primary_key=True)


class Cluster(Base):
    __tablename__ = "cluster"

    subtype_id: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(primary_key=True)
    subsubtype_id: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(primary_key=True)
    id: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(String(10), primary_key=True)

    __table_args__ = (
        ForeignKeyConstraint(
            [subtype_id, subsubtype_id], [SubSubType.subtype_id, SubSubType.id]
        ),
    )


engine.echo = True
Base.metadata.create_all(engine)
"""
CREATE TABLE subtype (
    id VARCHAR NOT NULL, 
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
)

CREATE TABLE subsubtype (
    subtype_id VARCHAR NOT NULL, 
    id VARCHAR(16) NOT NULL, 
    PRIMARY KEY (subtype_id, id), 
    FOREIGN KEY(subtype_id) REFERENCES subtype (id)
)

CREATE TABLE cluster (
    subtype_id VARCHAR NOT NULL, 
    subsubtype_id VARCHAR NOT NULL, 
    id VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL, 
    PRIMARY KEY (subtype_id, subsubtype_id, id), 
    FOREIGN KEY(subtype_id, subsubtype_id) REFERENCES subsubtype (subtype_id, id)
)
"""
```

Here's an [example](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/orm/join_conditions.html#overlapping-foreign-keys) for a similar situation from the SQLAlchemy docs.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I didn't even know you could pass those `__table_args__`. That neatly solves it, while retaining the declarative mapping